# what is $ \log(\exp(1+4i)) $?

Tags: complex-analysis

Using $\log(z) = \ln|z| + \arg(z)$ I get

$\log(\exp(1+4i)) = \ln(\exp(1+4i)) + i \cdot \arg(\exp(1+4i)) = 1+4i + i \cdot (4 + 2 \pi n) $

The solution is $ 1+4i + i2 \pi n$ where $n$ is a integer.

Where am I doing something wrong?

edit: I think I found my mistake: $\ln(\exp(1+4i))$ should be $ \ln|\exp(1+4i)| = 1 $

Comment: Your first term in the expression after the first equality should be $\ln{\left\vert\exp{(1 + 4 i)}\right\vert}$.

Comment: it is $1+4i-2\pi i$

Comment: Yes thank you Travis!

Comment: You're welcome.